# What is the difference between STL containers iterator and C pointer iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

i am writing a reverse iterator as a part of my own custom vector class. Up till now what i have written is as following.

```
class MyVector
{
  public:

  typedef T                           value_type;
  typedef value_type*                 pointer;
  typedef const value_type*           const_pointer;
  typedef value_type&                 reference;
  typedef const value_type&           const_reference;
  typedef pointer                     iterator;
  typedef const_pointer               const_iterator;
  typedef size_t                      size_type;

    class reverse_iterator
    {
        private:

        iterator iter;

        public:

        inline reverse_iterator(iterator a=0) : iter(a) {}
        inline reverse_iterator(const reverse_iterator& rev_iter) : iter(rev_iter.iter) {}
        inline reverse_iterator& operator++()
        {
            --iter;
            return *this;
        }
        // and remaining other operator functions
    };

  inline iterator begin (void) { return ((iterator)data_array);           }
  inline iterator end (void)   { return ((iterator)data_array+number_of_elements); }
  inline reverse_iterator      rbegin(void)    { return end()-1;}
  inline reverse_iterator      rend(void)      { return begin()-1;}


    //functions for myvector class 
}; //end of Myvector class
```

in above class iterater is just C style pointer and reverse_iterator is class. So when i do

```
    main()
    {
        myVector<int> i;
        myVector<int>::reverse_iterator rit= i.begin();
    }
```

my reverse_iterator is initialised with **begin()** function and code is compiling and running. But this does not happen in case of STL's iterator and reverse_iterator. They prevent such initialisation. e.g. reverse_iterator not allow himself to be initialised with **begin()** function, it must be initialised with **rbegin()**.

So what should i do to avoid such kind of initialization ?. Should i write a different iterator like which is in STL. And i think it is not possible to write it.. Please give me some solution...

Comment: You explicitly allow a conversion of `iterator` to `reverse_iterator` because you have given the latter a converting constructor from the former. Remove that constructor.

Comment: It would be easier if you reduced your code sample to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A lot of the code is irrelevant to the problem, yet there is not enough to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterators and reverse iterators have a few differences.

The most obvious: incrementing each iterator moves them in opposite directions.

Less obvious: the return of `begin()` is *not* the end of a reverse iterator. `begin()-1` would be. Remember that `end()` represents "one-past-the-end", as C++ ranges are half open, i.e. [begin, end). If you just swap `begin()` and `end()` in your reverse iterator then your reverse iterator will have the range (begin, end].

In other words, there's a reason why STL containers have both `begin()` and `end()` and `rbegin()` and `rend()`, even if the iterators and reverse iterators themselves might be compatible in some ways.

Answer (score 0):

To completely prevent conversion from `iterator` (pointer) to `reverse_iterator`, make the constructor of `reverse_iterator` private, and make `MyVector` a friend of `reverse_iterator`:

```
class MyVector
{
  // ...
  class reverse_iterator
  {
  private:
    friend class MyVector;
    reverse_iterator(iterator a=0) : iter(a) {}
    // ...
  };
  // ...
};
```

If you want that conversion available, but not automatic, then just make the corresponding constructor `explicit`.

```
class MyVector
{
  // ...
  class reverse_iterator
  {
  public:
    explicit reverse_iterator(iterator a=0) : iter(a) {}
    // ...
  };
  // ...
};
```

In an unrelated note, I also notice that your implementation of `rbegin()` probably invokes undefined behaviour (I can't tell for sure because it depends on the code initializing `data_array`): You are not allowed to decrement the pointer to the beginning of an array.

By the way, the keyword `inline` is not necessary in your case; if you write the member function body inside the class definition, it is automatically inline. Of course, the `inline` doesn't hurt either.